# Android application development: using hundreds of images

Tags: android, performance, image-processing

My question is that what is the best performance approach to put hundreds of images inside an android application? I have 900 images (6.0 MegaBytes) and I need to use them in a **ListView** inside **ImageViews**. The only options I have in mind are:

1. Inserting images into database and accessing them with query
2. Adding images to **drawable** and save their names in database and access images through their names

Thanks

Comment: What are the images ultimately being used for?  Are they tied to data being retrieved from an API?  I would consider storing the images on your API server or on a cloud-based image server such as AWS S3.  You can load them via normal http requests and then use caching within the app as needed.

Comment: You haven't given any information about what the images are for or how they are used. One thing I'd recommend though is to *NOT* store images themselves in a database - there are few DB systems which can handle that efficiently. If using a database, your second approach would be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks @SBerg413, I want to put the images inside my app (something standalone without any request to server or etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the kind of images, I'd like to propose:

3. Don't ship the images, but retrieve them using an internet connection when needed. Once you have retrieved image A, you can cache it on the SD card if necessary.

This is especially useful for when the images have some significant size (like photo's).

If your images are just small icons or something, just use the normal `drawable` approach.

Comment: Thanks, I exactly have 900 images (6.0 MegaByte). by this considerations what is your suggestion?

Comment: 900 images of 6MB each, or a total of 6MB for all images?

Comment: Weighing in the fact that each image is ~7kb, and you are showing them in a ListView, I'd use a network approach for that.